# What is the significance of using checked here

Tags: c#, .net

Can anyone elaborate following statement:

```
byte[] buffer = new Byte[checked((uint)Math.Min(32 * 1024, (int)objFileStream.Length))];
```

why i should not use

```
byte[] buffer = new Byte[32 * 1024];
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Attempt was to throw exception if `objFileStream.Length` will return number greater then `int.MaxValue` (2147483647), because `Length` on `Stream` returns `long` type (I assume `objFileStream` is stream). In **.net** arithmetic overflow is not checked by default.

Next code demonstrates this case:

```
long streamLength = long.MaxValue; //suppose buffer length is big

var res = checked( (int)(streamLength + 1) ); //exception will be thrown

Console.WriteLine( res ); //will print 0 in you comment checked keyword
```

After short analysis, you can reduce next statement

```
new Byte[checked((uint)Math.Min(32 * 1024, (int)objFileStream.Length))];
```

to

```
new Byte[Math.Min(32 * 1024, checked((int)objFileStream.Length))];
```

Personal recommendation: I don't see how `OverflowException` will help you here. `Math.Min` will ensuse, that array will be created no longer than `32768` items. If you try to `catch` somewhere in the calling method, you won't be able to deduce what is the reason of that error, it may come from anywhere in the called stack.

So you probably need not to always allocate array of size 32768 as you proposed

```
byte[] buffer = new Byte[32 * 1024];
```

but still use `Math.Min` so that you'll save storage, if `objFileStream.Length` will return small number

```
byte[] buffer = new Byte[Math.Min(32 * 1024, objFileStream.Length)];
```